# Прототип Маргариты – это Елена?

Tags: пунктуация

Что поставить на месте пропуска?

> Но, безусловно, прототип Маргариты – это Елена( )Елена Сергеевна Булгакова.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза странноватая. Там что, впереди по тексту есть перечисления разных женских имен, предлагавшихся на роль прототипа Маргариты? Тогда возможно двоеточие.
Если ничего подобного нет, то уберите первую Елену. Такой неожиданный акцент на имени жены Булгакова сильно бъет по мозгам.

ЗЫ Простите, не могу не бросить свои пять копеек насчет самого утверждения. Это далеко не так. Я думаю, что бессмысленно говорить о прототипе Маргариты, не определившись с прототипом Мастера. А на эту голгофу возводили не один десяток самых разных персон.

//=======

Нашел я "первоисточник". Да, в том контектсе я готов смирится с таким постоением фразы, хотя все равно она выглядит несколько искусственной. А знак там стоит один из возможных - и едва ли не лучший из таковых. Точка. ))) А если в одно предложение, то двоеточие или запятая.

Comment: Cогласен, странноватая. Не моя, к счастью. :)

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, тут все просто. После слова "Елена" — запятая. "Но, безусловно, прототип Маргариты – это Елена, Елена Сергеевна Булгакова".

Comment: Хочу напомнить о таком приеме, как парцелляция. Она очень хорошо привязывается к данной фразе, так что точка, о которой писал "b...", вполне уместна.